# issue with jquery tabs in IE versus Firefox

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm a newbie at this so if any way you could shed some light on it for me I would be very appreciative:

I am using a simple jquery tabs construct I found on a site that gives nice examples.  I got them working on my site, and they work great under FireFox and under IE8.  But IE9, Chrome and Safari -- the divisions that the tabs are supposed to switch to remain set at display=hidden.  I believe that the jquery code is supposed to modify the DOM object to set the currently-selected division to be display=block.

My call to jquery is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("ul.css-tabs").tabs("> .css-panes");
});
</script>
```

And my HTML markup is correct (I believe!).  It seems like in IE9 that jquery can't "find" the division to change its visibility, yet in Firefox it is able to.

Any hints of anything at all to look at to try to fix this would be appreciated...I'm driving myself nuts trying to fix it...

EDIT:  Here is the basic construct of my markup:

```
<div class="prodtabs">

  <ul class="css-tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Specs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contents</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Warranty</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="css-panes">
    <p>stuff on tab 1</p><br />
  </div> <!-- css-panes -->

  <div class="css-panes">
    <p>stuff on tab 2</p><br />
  </div> <!-- css-panes -->

  <div class="css-panes">
    <p>stuff on tab 3</p><br />
  </div> <!-- css-panes -->

  <div class="css-panes">
    <p>stuff on tab 4</p><br />
  </div> <!-- css-panes -->

</div> <!-- prodtabs -->
```

Now, this is wrapped pretty deeply in other stuff (I am using a slightly-modified version of WordPress to serve up these pages) -- so I can't tell what is breaking this jquery call when I'm in IE9 or Chrome, versus it working fine in FireFox...

Comment: I don't think that's a valid selector. Try `$('ul.css-tabs > .css-panes').tabs()`.

Comment: let's see your html structure, and perhaps a link to the tabs examples you found?

Comment: my page is here:  www.autobody101.com/content/devilbiss-spray-guns/ and the example I used is from here:  http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/multiple.html

Comment: thanks minitech but that change breaks it on every browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be seen in IE console. Your videobox.js script is throwing an error in IE freezing scripts on page . Remove that and tabs will work.

You also have Mootools in page. My guess is video script is  mootools script. mootools also uses the same "$" object as jQuery but I don't believe they offer a method not to collide with jQuery.

jQuery however offers a solution with noConflict() method, full details found here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: It was quicker than I thought  to try your suggestion -- it WORKS!!  Thank you so much!!  I have been awake for 32 hours working on my site and trying to solve that problem.  If you were here I would hug you - so you are probably glad you are not here :-)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="prodtabs">

<ul class="css-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Specs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Contents</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Images</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Warranty</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1" class="css-panes">
    <p>stuff on tab 1</p><br />
</div> <!-- css-panes -->

<div id="tabs-2" class="css-panes">
    <p>stuff on tab 2</p><br />
</div> <!-- css-panes -->

<div id="tabs-3" class="css-panes">
    <p>stuff on tab 3</p><br />
</div> <!-- css-panes -->

<div id="tabs-4" class="css-panes">
    <p>stuff on tab 4</p><br />
</div> <!-- css-panes -->

</div> <!-- prodtabs -->
```

**JS**

```
$("div.prodtabs").tabs();
```

**Reference:** http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs

Comment: Thanks Sheikh - it doesn't work though.  I like the idea of using distinct ids for each pane -- but my pages render with multiple instances of these tabs on one page, so I have to use my version of the jquery selector -- it will not work with your version.

Comment: Thanks, where can I find a reference of that kind of tab system ?

Comment: Sheikh look around this site:  flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/multiple.html  I found it to be an excellent resource.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic HTML and JavaScript seem to work (at least it did for me in Chrome and IE9): http://jsfiddle.net/qTuLz/11/

Perhaps try adding the CSS you are using for your site and see if the problem is there?

Comment: WOW - that jsfiddle tool is very cool I had no idea it even existed.  Yup, I added my CSS and also another instance of tabs (I have multiple on one page) -- and it works fine in Chrome.  Sigh...so that means "something else" is breaking it on my site.  I guess I should just add my HTML, working outward, until it breaks (?)

Comment: That's usually my way of solving these types of problems :)